# Are these equivalent summations?

Tags: summation

I just want to ask if
 $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i |a_i \bar b_j-a_j\bar b_i|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_i \bar b_j-a_j\bar b_i)(\bar a_ib_j + \bar a_j b_i)$$

is  true and possibly an explanation on why the summations change from $\sum^n$ to to $\sum^i$

Comment: I didn't spot the sign change in the second factor of the summand on the RHS. The summands are not equal.

Comment: @JohnBentin if there was not a sign change would it be equal?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. As a counterexample, take $n=2$, $a_2=b_1=1$, and $a_1=b_2=0$. Then the left-hand side equals $1$ while the right-hand side equals $0$.